# FileDialog in RAP 2.1 - Add bundle Dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, bundle

I tried this [tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/06/23/uploading-files-with-rap-14/) with my RAP 2.1. I downloaded my bundle from [FileUpload](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/incubator/2.1/fileupload/) (you can find it from [Eclipse Rap Incubator](http://eclipse.org/rap/incubator/). After it I wanted to add a bundle dependency to org.eclipse.rap.rwt.supplemental.filedialog to my project. So I tried Run Configuration -> Bundles -> Add Required. But can't find my supplemental.filedialog. So I tried to add it to the required dependencies from my plugin.xml but it also not working.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using this (http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/incubator/2.1/fileupload/) p2 repository for getting the FileUpload bundles. Please make sure that org.eclipse.rap.rwt.supplemental.fileupload and org.eclipse.rap.rwt.supplemental.filedialog bundles exist in your target platform. Make sure that you have Appache Commons IO/FileUpload bundles also (get them from Orbit).

Answer (score 1):

Why you not upgrade to RAP 2.2?

Repository here:

http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/incubator/2.2

Change Dependency from `org.eclipse.rap.rwt.supplemental.filedialog` to `org.eclipse.rap.addons.filedialog`